# Is there a way I can overwrite LESS variable with LESS compiler in PHP?

Tags: php, css, less

Currently I am using the [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) as my LESS compiler. I know it provides a way to set the LESS variables, but is there a way to overwrite the variables set in the file?

For example, I have the following LESS file:

```
@theme-color: #000055;
h1 {
    color: @theme-color;
}
h2 {
    color: @theme-color * 1.3;
}
h3 {
    color: @theme-color * 1.5;
}
```

To compile it in PHP,

```
require"path/to/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php";
$less = new lessc;
$less->setVariables(array(
    "theme-color" => "#000055"
));
$less->compileFile("basic/path/less/main.less", "basic/path//css/main.css");
```

It successfully compile the file but the variable @theme-color is not overwritten. Is there a way to overwrite it?

I don't mind using another compiler if necessary, but it needs to be server side as the javascript compiler is too slow and it creates a moment of no css view.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php) you can unset a variable. If setting a variable does not override the LESS variable then maybe you can unset it and then set it?

Comment: The problem is that the variables are set in the file. No matter what I have done before loading the file, the result is overwritten by the settings in the LESS file.

Answer (score 3):

Possible you can use `compile()` instead of `compileFile()`;

```
$lesscode = file_get_contents("basic/path/less/main.less");
$lesscode .= "@themecolor: #000055;";

file_put_contents("basic/path//css/main.css", $less->compile($lesscode));
```

Comment: This should work for some case, but as my less file contains include command, this will makes the include statement fails as the path is different.

Comment: you can set he import directory for the `less` object http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#import_directory

Comment: Thanks. I have overlooked that. This answer works then.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no way to do that with leafo's [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) compiler. At last I have changed to use oyejorge's [lessphp](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/#basic-use) compiler.

With the oyejorge's lessphp compiler, the variable can be changed after loading the file and at the same time able to include file:

```
$parser = new Less_Parser();
$parser->parseFile( "path/to/less/main.less", url("path/to/less/") );
$parser->ModifyVars( array('theme-color'=>'#005500') );
$css = $parser->getCss();
```