# Setting Sass variables into Sass.compile_file

Tags: ruby, sass

Is it possible to inject variables into the Sass scope when using the method `Sass.compile_file`?

Currently I'm passing values into the `custom:` argument, creating a custom sass function, and then calling that from within the Sass file/script. This is very awkward as I have to create objects of the appropriate types to return from the functions, i.e. `Sass::Script::String`, rather than `String`.

Answer (score 0):

I think according [Is there a way I can overwrite LESS variable with LESS compiler in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887092/is-there-a-way-i-can-overwrite-less-variable-with-less-compiler-in-php/29893778#29893778) you can open the file yourself and parse its contents through (`Sass.compile`)[http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass.html] instead of using  `Sass.compile_file` directly.

With `compile.rb` :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby    
require 'sass'
data = File.read("./colors.scss")
puts Sass::compile('$color: white;' + data)
```

and `colors.scss`:

```
$color: blue !default;
p {
color: $color;
}
```

Running `./compile.rb` outputs:

```
p {
  color: white; }
```

According [the docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass) you should use [`Sass::Engine`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Engine.html):

> Using Sass in Ruby code is very simple. After installing the Sass gem,
>   you can use it by running require "sass" and using Sass::Engine.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'sass'
template = File.read('./colors.scss')
sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new("$color: white;\n" + template, :syntax => :scss)
output = sass_engine.render
puts output
```